# NullPointerException при использовании SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, дата

Пытаюсь получить дату определенного формата:

```
String pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
formatter.format(department.getStartDate());
```

Программа при этом валится с ошибкой:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1770)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:943)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:936)
at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:345)
at CSV.Export.generateCSV(Export.java:49)
at Main.main(Main.java:17)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

StartDate при этом имеет тип Date:

```
package Entity;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.Date;

public class Department {
    @Getter @Setter private Date startDate;
}
```

С чем может быть связана данная проблема?

Comment: Возможно, значением `startDate` является `null`. Вы его проверяли?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ошибка в том, что `department.getStartDate()` возвращает `null`.

Вот такой код

```
String pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
formatter.format(null);
```

даете следующий результат

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1770)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:943)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:936)
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:345)
```

Как видите исключение совпадает с вашим.